# How to forward a Typescript generic type into inner function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to implement a function which abstract the concept of "module". Each module can accept a defined input. I'm having troubles trying to accept generic inputs.

Below a minimal reproducible example to give proper context:

```
// Signature of module creator
const createModule = <TInput>(callback: (arg: TInput) => void) => {
    // do stuff with callback
}

// This works smoothly:
type ButtonInput = { onTap: () => void };
const button = createModule<ButtonInput>((config) => {
// do something with config.onTap
// [ ... ]
})

// This is the tricky one:

// Sample generic function
const modalRef = <T extends Record<string, string>>() => {}

type ModalInput<T extends Record<string, string>> = { value: T };
const modal = createModule<ModalInput<T>>((config) => {
// ------------------------------ ^^^ Cannot find name 'T'.(2304)
// I need to access the generic parameter inside the callback
const ref = modalRef<T>()
// ------ --------- ^^^ Cannot find name 'T'.(2304)
// [ ... ] do stuff with ref
})
```

How would you approach the problem?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=27&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAehAIFkEsDtoLYEMA25EAcUFMHdgC5IHQD2s4pAZuAqQCYCuO4AxgE7bGnvCvkBnAm07FskBs2zgAvOAA8AFQCSsDIwIA+ABStUKAEZJWAawBc4bUnYBzCyrUaAlLM3gAbqWj0XMtwG9gcGDwTgJGdgo9FENjE2AAX2BQCEUAC2gBcAB3HhMsgTpSAjSUAE8zYAIyjGkAIQ0CclV1YTl-SlhFJAwLbV83T29wBIBuPkFhA0bSBFkRLgJxSRx5BoIm2BaNHV1yKmgbAfBAkPAwcHpScAFZ7BK4GxzoErZ9w4A6cm6MIJCLgDa4A+IPAAF1Ek5kilwOlMugsiVpAR2NBTGVOtgLMkLgBlJAILDSGz4bCo1jgKiMWCsEjkCawIS0BioABK2BociUOmO-iSVRq0gk9FQ2wI3PmHXcqEYWNhI3G-EZwjoIrQcg4i2WTFWwtFjnFik0uyVByOrhOf2CFwAtHb7Q7HU7nXbwAA9D3gADCSFgsGKlLg9HAsAJ0gA5Ipwx9tAAmADMAAYACxQs4XZQh7DYYNNcDGVjYASItLE0nk8AYaxhpbsdCM7zI0tsfRGUxWt7K0Ic+aqtkc7n9Du2x3gF0292en1+gMHWDB0N4cCR6NxpOpjthCIUThUSFAA)

Comment: You can't, really. You'll need declare the generic on the callback that you are passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue your seeing is due to the way you're trying to use the generic type **`T`** outside of its scope. Generics are scoped to the functions (or classes or interfaces) where they're defined. In the line `const modal = createModule<ModalInput<T>>((config) => {...}`, the type **`T`** isn't in scope, so the TypeScript compiler has no idea what it is.

```
// Signature of module creator
const createModule = <TInput>(callback: (arg: TInput) => void) => {
    // do stuff with callback
}

// This works smoothly:
type ButtonInput = { onTap: () => void };
const button = createModule<ButtonInput>((config) => {
    // do something with config.onTap
    // [ ... ]
});

// Sample generic function
const modalRef = <T extends Record<string, string>>() => {};

// Adjusted type for ModalInput
type ModalInput<T extends Record<string, string>> = { value: T };

// Approach the modal creation with a function 
// so we can scope the generic properly.
function createModal<T extends Record<string, string>>() {
    return createModule<ModalInput<T>>((config) => {
        const ref = modalRef<T>();
        // [ ... ] do stuff with ref
    });
}

// Example usage:
const myModal = createModal<{ title: string }>();
```

**This is how i would implement it**: [Playground Updated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/PTAEGUEsHMDsEMAuBXATgU1AewGagLZYAmyANpgMYZJaoBQFWsAzoqFekugLLFmYBeUAB4AKgElYAB2SIAfAAoK8UqQBG8CgGsAXKAXxU0PROmyAlKAFzQANyyQil66ADedUJ9AhQRLKFZkHDwAd0hEAAt2FXVNLToAXzo6H1EIyGZQENotTOZCLEjSAE8dOkRiqUwAIVlEJkkZNiFXbFhReCk9BWcbe0dQBIBuBiZWUDU6pit2akQePnJhWsR62EbZRSUmHBhetw8vHz8ArHx0SMhYaCzwqMZYXegAOiYOqUPPHwBtUGf-0AAXUS5hGKTA4Hg%20Ck5FA0HQsHQqEgFFAOGQsAoiEgTFGLDYhCIKgASug8EIxKB0AAPeawIiZUmMVBEYSsZHXAA0AUQHOgckU%201cw2SPgAgkQAFbIVjoIigCpVNG0UC8ImkDaIcqVTBqlSayk0ukM0BM2is9lXaDcy3XAUzVq2FTIdAmQZg8VSKSoLCaKKRTCElSzTjY6ZhSKgeBojFYnGwUDg05ZSjwBPMRhKgNwhFIlGgb1YKqoErPOjozFhhMcLh60iG2kIk1mlls3lWm3tu2Cg5eUAYFCoatzBYkJZ1g2iAUKbaPPZWGzuPt9h7jDDkgjEElksSCkbLo5gX7-Z5A3z%20QLBW6R9efQagxKisAAUWpUJhmBl8HhZVXBOKdYzDW8x1sIrTYog5B6LaNwJHudBAA)

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you! I ended up using it. Just food for thought, [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAgG1w) is another potential idea, which leverages the type argument as constraint. The problem still is that the return value of the function does not recognize the type.